# Can we check smoothness of a morphism after base change to the algebraic closure?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness, smoothness, galois-descent

I know that smoothness is fppf local on the base, but this is not enough because taking algebraic closures is not finitely presented. The reason I'm asking this is because I want an easy/quick argument or a reference (which I did not find).

If it helps, I'm looking at a surjective homomorphism of Abelian varieties $f:A \to B$ over some field $k$, and I know that $f_{\overline{k}}$ is smooth, but I want to show that $f$ is smooth.

Comment: Smoothness is fpqc local on the base

Comment: @Exitpath That's great, thanks!

Comment: There are some very useful tables with various results like this in Poonen's book "rational points on varieties".